# Sending requests using twitterAPI

Tags: c#, twitter

I'm starting to learn how to use the TwitterAPI and WebClient class, and I've tried to follow a simple GET request by twitter :

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets

In the example, they've wrote :

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23freebandnames&since_id=24012619984051000&max_id=250126199840518145&result_type=mixed&count=4
```

this is my code :

```
    public static string TwitterSearch()
    {
        string data;
        WebClient web = new WebClient();
        web.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

        string url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23freebandnames&since_id=24012619984051000&max_id=250126199840518145&result_type=mixed&count=4";
        data = web.DownloadString(url);

        return data;
    }
```

though I get Bad Request (400) Error.

Why is that? it is just like in the tutorials...

Thanks!

Comment: They probably want a `User-Agent`.

Comment: I've added a User Agent

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are missing the authentication all together.

> [Using the Twitter Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) Please note that now API v1.1
>   requires that the request must be authenticated, check [Authentication
>   & Authorization](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth) documentation for more details on how to do it.

Make sure you have added the authorization header.

```
_Request.Headers.Add( "Authorization", string.Format( "Basic {0}", BearerTokenCredentials ) );
    _Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
```

Comment: Bit how can someone properly format the request using WebClient()?